# To update some Arch certain packages only

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

How do we update some certain packages by use pacman ?

E.g how do we update only packages (in regex syntax) py.+  as:

```
$ sudo pacman -S 'py.+' 
error: target not found: py.+
```

not work
Please help out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, on Arch Linux, [partial upgrades are not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported); you should always upgrade the whole system at once (`pacman -Syu`) and upgrade the whole system when installing new packages (`pacman -Syu package`).
`pacman -S package` would install the version of *`package`* that is currently in your sync database, likely reinstalling the already installed version.
`pacman -Sy` followed by `pacman -S package` would update the sync database and then install the latest version of *`package`* *and its dependencies*, possibly breaking other installed packages that depend on older versions of the latter.
As noted in the wiki page linked above, `pacman -Syuw` followed by `pacman -S package` is not a solution either.

That said, based on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman), a common way to give `pacman` a list of packages as arguments is to generate it using another `pacman` instance. For example, to get the details about a list of installed packages whose name *or description*<sup>1</sup> starts with `py` (but is not just `py`), filtering out foreign ones:

```bsh
pacman -Qsq '^py[^ ]+$' | xargs pacman -Qnq | xargs -o pacman -Si
```

Where `xargs` is used to avoid "argument list too long" errors.

When dealing with package names, the assumption that they will not contain whitespace, quoting, globbing or otherwise uncommon characters is safe. Leaving command substitions unquoted would otherwise be a likely bad idea<sup>2</sup>; just make sure the value of `IFS` does not include any characters that may appear in package names.

The non standard `xargs`'s `-o` option (usually available on Arch Linux, which by default ships its GNU implementation), which tells `xargs` to reopen  standard input as `/dev/tty` and make it available to the executed command, would be necessary when running `pacman` commands that require user interaction (though not actually needed in the above example).

Alternatively, if you feel confident the number of packages returned by your search will be small, you may use nested command substitutions:

```bsh
pacman -Si $(pacman -Qnq $(pacman -Qsq '^py[^ ]+$'))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Other utilities may be needed to perform a regexp search on *names* only, e.g. `pacsift` (from [pacutils](https://archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=pacutils&maintainer=&flagged=)) or [`expac`](https://archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=expac&maintainer=&flagged=). Note that `pacman`'s search options also check the "provides" field of packages.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/315749), [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/315749) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/315749).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

it is sort of supported, you can just use --ignore package1,package2 and ignore everything

so sudo or doas pacman -Syu --ignore vim,firefox,linux